# compare elements positions in first array with another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i got stucked on a game when i need to compare two arrays. Both arrays contain numbers. First array got numbers sorted and second one has numbers in user order. What i try to achieve is : compare these arrays and find wrong position in user array(if exists) and return the number on wrong position.

What i have tryed:

```
var a = ["1","2","3","4","5"];
var d = ["1","2","3","5","4"];

function checkArrays( arrA, arrB ){

    if(arrA.length !== arrB.length) return false;

    var cA = arrA.slice().sort().join(","); 
    var cB = arrB.slice().sort().join(",");

    return cA===cB;

}
```

**EDIT:** `randomArrayGenerated.push(generateRandoms(0,99));` - where generateRandoms is a function. While in for i push in randomArrayGenerated some numbers so the length of array varies.

`correctOrderArray.push(randomArrayGenerated.sort(function(x, y){return x-y}));` - adding in correctOrderArray , the elements from random array but sorted.

`userArray.push(userOrder);` - where userOrder is a variable which gets value from an input.

IF `userArray.length == correctOrderArray.length` - i'd like to compare these arrays using `correctOrderArray.find(function(a, b){ return a !== userArray[b] })`

Why doesnt work? (Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function)

Comment: cant you do this really easily with a for loop?

Comment: do you need to confirm that they both have all numbers, or do you just wanna know the first number that is in the wrong position?

Comment: i need to check if wrong positioned numbers exists in user array compared to sorted array and return the numbers(not the position) in wrong position from user array. Like in example above if we compare a with b where b is user array, i just need to return 5,4 or 4,5 doesnt matter the order coz as you can see 4 and 5 are switched if you compare with a array.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = ["1","2","3","4","5"];
var d = ["1","2","3","5","4"];
var wrongPositioned = false;

function checkArrays( arrA, arrB ){

    if(arrA.length !== arrB.length) return false;

    for (var i = 0; i< arrA.length; i++) {
        if (arrA[i] !== arrB[i]) {
           wrongPositioned = {
               position: i, 
               value: arrA[i],
               userValue: arrB[i],
               valuePositionInUser: arrA.indexOf(arrB[i])
           };
           break;  
        }
    }

    return wrongPositioned;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its just a loop.

```
function checkArrays( arrA, arrB ){
    for(var i = 0; i < arrA.length; i++) { if(arrA[i] !== arrB [i]) return arrB [i] };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hL257bh6/

If you're allowed to use ECMAScript 6

```
a.find(function(v, i){ return v !== d[i] })
```

Comment: Do not use return in a for loop

Comment: and after, return -1;

Comment: @Shiala yes, the intention is to return the matching value from the  the function. As per the question, I don't see any value in creating an additional variable.

Comment: @Shiala. Nope, it wont. It's  an entirely legitimate usage of return. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#Example:_Interrupt_a_function

Comment: Yeah I thought it would but that's only when you're not inside a function

Comment: I'd like to use @SamGreenhalgh 's code, but i think i'm wrong somewhere... can you check edit, pls?...

Comment: @Proless I've added a jsfiddle, maybe it will be easiest to copy from there?